# Can encrypt data with .net application and decrypt then with database function?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, encryption, aes

I am facing this question:
I am using .net core application with nhibernate. Can I encrypt some columns with aes in my application and then have a function in db that an decrypt data for querying reporting?

this is my encrypt c# code

```
string EncryptData(string textData, string Encryptionkey)  
{  
    RijndaelManaged objrij = new RijndaelManaged();  
    //set the mode for operation of the algorithm   
    objrij.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;  
    //set the padding mode used in the algorithm.   
    objrij.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;  
    //set the size, in bits, for the secret key.   
    objrij.KeySize = 0x80;  
    //set the block size in bits for the cryptographic operation.    
    objrij.BlockSize = 0x80;  
    //set the symmetric key that is used for encryption & decryption.    
    byte[] passBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Encryptionkey);  
    //set the initialization vector (IV) for the symmetric algorithm    
    byte[] EncryptionkeyBytes = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };  

    int len = passBytes.Length;  
    if (len > EncryptionkeyBytes.Length)  
    {  
        len = EncryptionkeyBytes.Length;  
    }  
    Array.Copy(passBytes, EncryptionkeyBytes, len);  

    objrij.Key = EncryptionkeyBytes;  
    objrij.IV = EncryptionkeyBytes;  

    //Creates a symmetric AES object with the current key and initialization vector IV.    
    ICryptoTransform objtransform = objrij.CreateEncryptor();  
    byte[] textDataByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textData);  
    //Final transform the test string.  
    return Convert.ToBase64String(objtransform.TransformFinalBlock(textDataByte, 0, textDataByte.Length));  
}
```

and this is my decryption function in oracle

```
key VARCHAR2(64) := 'THE KEY';

encryption_type    PLS_INTEGER :=          -- total encryption type
                            DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT_AES256
                          + DBMS_CRYPTO.CHAIN_CBC
                          + DBMS_CRYPTO.PAD_PKCS5;

DBMS_CRYPTO.DECRYPT(
    src => data2decrypt,
    typ => encryption_type,
    key => key  
)
```

Comment: Your decryption attempt is not using the same padding mechanism as the original encryption.  I don't think `DBMS_CRYPTO` supports PKCS7 padding.  Can you change your C# program to use PKCS5?

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak PKCS5 and PKCS7 padding is the same thing for all intends and purposes: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/9044/13022

Comment: You need to replicate the same method. I don't see that you use the same way to stretch the password into the key size of 16 bytes in Oracle. Also, I don't see where you use the IV and various encoding steps might be missing depending on whether Oracle is doing them automatically or not.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Really?  I thought PKCS5 was essentially a subset of PKCS7.  That is, PKCS5 is PKCS7 but using 8 byte blocks.  But the OP seems to be using 16 byte blocks in his encryption code (hex 0x80 bits).  Perhaps `objrij.BlockSize = 0x80;` needs to be `objrij.BlockSize = 0x40;` ?

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak Yes, but Rijndael is only defined for block sizes of 128, 192 and 256 bit. A block size of 64 bit is not possible, so PKCS5 would also not be possible, but it still works for backwards compatibility when block ciphers were only 64 bit wide such as DES.

Comment: ok, so i use exactly the same settings it can be done. tooday i make the suggested changes and test it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my answer won't suit you, but as far as I am concerned it's the simplest one. MSSQL lets you create functions in C#. So I would create a C# function to do data encryption/decryption and add it to SqlServer (you should create a dll for that). I would also use this dll in C# application.

Comment: That's sensible, yes, but it looks like OP is using Oracle.

Comment: exactly. i have to use oracle db